# Debugging stored procedure while in use with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, visual-studio-debugging

I have DocumentItem entity mapped to insert/update/delete stored procedures in Entity Framework edmx.

I'm trying to insert a new Document into the databse along with its DocumentItems. The whole operation is enclosed in a transaction, and it's not easy to debug separately.

This is why I would like to try to debug the sp 'live' - when it's called from entity framework. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Just use profiler to see what data EF sends to stored procedure and use that data separately to test / debug only stored procedure. Debugging it together requires you to set debugging session for both .NET code and SQL code and place breakpoint into stored procedure prior to calling `SaveChanges` on your context. In theory it could work but I never use that.

Comment: How can I start a debugging session for a SQL server? I assume this should work somehow similar to "Attach to process" in VS.

Comment: "You can not step into a T-SQL or CLR store procedure from client code (managed or native)." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2006/06/29/651644.aspx